# MySQL проблема с агрегированными функциями и having или не понимание как их правильно использовать

Tags: mysql

Написал запрос для базы данных Sakila в MySQL, который должен находить продавца, который совершил сделок на минимальную сумму
написал запрос

```
select summ, first_name, last_name
from
(
    select  sum(amount) as summ, first_name, last_name
    from payment, staff
    where staff.staff_id = payment.staff_id
    group by first_name, last_name
) as T1
having summ = min(summ)
```

Работает он неправильно, ничего не выводит, но самое удивительно то, что если поменять min на max, то все правильно, находит продавца с максимальной суммой.
Я могу запрос переписать через where summ = (вложенный запрос), но я хочу понять почему такая проблема.

Answer (score 1):

having используется с агрегированными функциями. В данном случает во внешнем запросе никакого агрегирования нету, поэтому having здесь не будет работать, но будет работать where.